# Tomcat 9 adding more slash to url problem

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, url, tomcat9

I am facing a issue actually it is not a big deal but i need to solve this problem for my work.
When I write url like http://localhost:8080/****/Pages/Home.jsp it works fine but or when i try an unbeing page like http://localhost:8080/****/Pages/Hoxxxxme.jsp it redirects to my 404 error page.but when try like http://localhost:8080/****/Pages//Home.jsp loads a page but not proper way ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mklV.png) or http://localhost:8080/****/Pages/xxx/Home.jsp (unbeing page) it tries to redirect to 404 error page but not a proper way again [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9kUo.png)

I could not understand the problem.I tried mime type in web.xml, It didnt work.How can I solve this problem?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CredIS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<!--   <listener>
    <listener-class>com.crede.system.SessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.crede.system.ContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

   <filter>
       <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
        


 -->  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>32</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  
 <!-- BLOCK COMMENT FOR TEST LINK. REMOVE COMMENTS FOR PRODUCTION -->
 <!--<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <user-data-constraint>
 <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
 </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint> -->
 <!-- BLOCK COMMENT FOR TEST LINK. REMOVE COMMENTS FOR PRODUCTION -->
 </web-app>
```

Comment: `Home.jsp`, `Hoxxxme.jsp` and `xxx/Home.jsp` are different pages - what do you expect?

Comment: @dan1st Home.jsp is valid page but the others not.Hoxxxme.jsp is ok i am gettin 404 server error.but for xxx/Home.jsp, I cant get 404 error in proper way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show the web.xml and the location of the Home.jsp file (or handler) in the project?

Comment: @dan1st  which web.xml? if u asking inside web-inf which i just realized that i need add in that. Now I am trying a new library of tuckey. inside of web.inf is now ; 
edited in post

Comment: There should only be a single `web.xml` file.

Comment: @dan1st and Home.jsp location :

C:\Users\USER\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Company\Pages